# Unable to interpret these sentences: 「まいばんくにのかぞくにでんわします」「このまちにはゆうめいな建物があります」

Tags: grammar, syntax, synonyms

Hi there I was given a couple of exercises, from which I can figure more or less the right answer but I can't interpret it totally (I see no logic between the sentences and the possible reply)

First one:

> まいばん くにの かぞくに でんわしました

I understand it as:

"Every night, the family of the country was making a phone call."

I don't understand if it's referring to the country population, like in "country music", the family of someone or someone else.

The answers are:

[image]

So by using the context (まいばん) I chose the third from top to bottom, but I don't clearly understand it.

Second sentence:

> このまちには ゆうめいな建物があります

"This city has a famous building."

With the answers:

[image]

I think the first option is the right one, but only by the ビル word as a synonym, the others are tea, cake and park, but what's the meaning of the sentence and the answer?

**UPDATE**
As noted by Jarmanso7, the first sentence is in past while the answers are in present. I made a typo when making the post

Posted>

```
まいばん くにの かぞくに でんわしました
```

Should be

```
まいばん くにの かぞくに でんわします
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First sentence**

> まいばん くにの かぞく**に** でんわします。
>   I call my family at my home country every evening.

First of all, the family is not making the call, but someone (probably the speaker, it could be someone else) is making a phone call **to** the family, because it is marked with the particle に. The particle に marks the goal or destination of the action, in this case, whom the call is made to.

国【くに】の家族【かぞく】 is used to talk about the family you have in your country of origin or homeland. Presumably, the speaker is now in a foreign country and makes a phone call to his family who are living at his home country.

Your answer is correct. We know that:

1 - The answer must be either the 1st or the 3rd sentence because they start by よる (evening/night), and in the original sentence it is said まいばん (every evening). 2nd and 4th don't make sense because they start by あさ (morning).

2 - The answer must be either the 3rd or the 4th sentence because they use いつも (always), and in the original sentence it is said まいばん (every evening). If it is every evening, then it is always. 1st and 2nd don't make sense because they use ときどき (sometimes).

So, the only option that is coherent with the time (よる) and the frequency (いつも) is the 3rd sentence.

---

**Second sentence**

> このまちにはゆうめいな建物があります。
>   In this city there is a famous building.

You interpreted the second sentence correctly, although I'd say "In this city **there is** a famous building" rather than "this city *has* a famous building", because the verb ある means "to exist, to be". Anyway, the final meaning is the same.

You are right about the answer, too. It is the first one because it is the only that talks about a building (建物/ビル). The sentence structure is the same for the four options, it just replaces the word ビル by other substantives.

I think you are doing pretty well, just keep learning new vocabulary and you will see how you figure out this kind of exercises more easily.

---

As a reference, I write down how I would translate each sentence so you can understand them better.

> **よる** は **ときどき** くにのかぞくにでんわします。
>   **At night**, I **sometimes** call the family at my country.
>
> **あさ** は **ときどき** くにのかぞくにでんわします。
>   **In the morning**, I **sometimes** call the family at my country.
>
> **よる** は **いつも** くにのかぞくにでんわします。
>   **At night**, I **always** call the family at my country.
>
> **あさ**は **いつも** くにのかぞくにでんわします。
>   **In the morning**, I **always** call the family at my country.
>
> このまちにはゆうめいな**ビル**があります。
>   In this city there is a famous **building**.
>
> このまちにはゆうめいな**おちゃ**があります。
>   In this city there is a famous **tea**.
>
> このまちにはゆうめいな**ケーキ**があります。
>   In this city there is a famous **cake**.
>
> このまちにはゆうめいな**こうえん**があります。
>   In this city there is a famous **park**.

Comment: Thanks , you are very kind. Im studying for the December test. Your help is very detailed and useful!!

Comment: Then since the subject its most of the times omitted, Its safe to assume the speaker as 1st person?

Comment: and the second sentence the "there is" part is the があります, Im guessing.

Comment: The subject is usually omitted so you need to know the contrxt. If you don't know it, just guess for each sentence. For example, if I were to say なにをしていますか。what [are you] doing ? it's safe to assume that the subject is "you", because it's a very direct question. So it really depends on each case and the context.

Comment: You're welcome! I am studying for this december test as well. がんばりましょう！

Comment: 毎度 ありがとう ございます! Good luck!

Comment: @jarmanso7 +1, not doubting your analysis here, but I'm baffled as to what the 'question' is that makes these sentences the 'answer'.

Comment: @user3856370 I think it's a paraphrasing exercise, so the actual requierement of the exercise could be: "Given a first sentence, and a set of option sentences, select the option sentence with the closest meaning to the first sentence". It's one of the [question types appearing in the Japanese Language Proficiency Test (日本語能力試験試験)](http://www.passjapanesetest.com/jlpt-format/).

Comment: This certainly fits with the second exercise presented here. However, it is somewhat strange that the question sentence of the first exercise here has the verb in past tense while the possible answers are in present tense. If the original sentence were in present tense,「まいばん くにの かぞくに でんわします」it would be congruent with the presented answers. @ricc_s0x, are you sure the first sentence in your exercise has the verb in its past form「しました」 instead of 「します」? Could you check it? This point baffles me as well tbh. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jarmanso7 , let me check this. I didn't note the detail.

Comment: @jarmanso7, I'm posting an update

Comment: @jarmanso7, you make detailed observations, great work!

Comment: If that's the case, I'll update the answer accordingly as well. Thanks for reviewing it!